# What is the difference between a question and an invitation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What is the difference between a question and an invitation?

Is there any difference?
Do they accomplish different things? 
Are they structurally different?

Comment: What is the *similarity* between a question and an invitation? I mean, an invitation can be phrased as a question, but so can a lot of other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize that Stephen's answer is pretty thorough, but can't help but think that side-by-side comparison of their definitions may help a bit, so...

> Question: Noun: A sentence worded or expressed so as to elicit information.

and

> Invitation: A written or verbal request inviting someone to go somewhere or to do something.

So the answer to your question "Do they accomplish different things?" is "Yes".
They do. ***question*** is for obtaining information, and ***invitation*** is more for giving information.

Comment: It sounds like a question elicits information, whereas an invitation elicits an action. Is that fair to say?

Comment: @dsg I think so. Absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

An invitation is a statement or question that says are welcome to a party or an event. A question is something which you want answered.

Example of a question:

> Where is your party?

In this example you expect an answer. "The party is at my house."

Examples of an invitation as a statement:

> You may come to my party.
>   You are invited to my party.

Here you just make it clear that the other person may attend.

Example of an invitation as a question:

> Will you come to my party?

Both are considered invitations but one expects a response on whether or not you are coming.

Comment: Does this relate at all to speech acts?

Comment: Yes, and invitation is an example of a speech act.